# Rewrite file content with new content

Tags: python

In a program - the program doesn't matter -, only the first lines, I open an empty file (named empty.txt).
Then I define functions, but never use them on main ... so, I do not actually write anything.

This the nearly complete code:

```
from os import chdir
 
chdir('C:\\Users\\Julien\\Desktop\\PS BOT')
 
fic=open('empty.txt','r+')
 
def addtodic(txt):
    """Messages de la forme !add id,message ; txt='id,message' """
    fic.write(txt+'\n')
    fic.seek(0)
 
def checkdic(txt):
    """Messages de la forme !lien id ; txt='id' """
    for i in fic.readlines().split('\n'):
        ind=i.index(',')
        if i[:ind]==txt:
            fic.seek(0)
            return i[ind+1:]
    fic.seek(0)
    return 'Not found'
```

Then I launch it, and using the console, I simply ask "fic.write( 'tadam' )", like, to check if the writing works well before moving on.

```
%run "C:/Users/Julien/Desktop/PS BOT/dic.py"
 
fic
Out[8]: <open file 'empty.txt', mode 'r+' at 0x0000000008D9ED20>
 
fic.write('tadam')
 
fic.readline()
Out[10]: 'os import chdir\n'
 
fic.readline()
Out[11]: "chdir('C:\\\\Users\\\\Julien\\\\Desktop\\\\PS BOT')\n"
 
fic.readline()
Out[12]: '\n'
 
fic.readline()
Out[13]: "fic=open('empty.txt','r+')\n"
 
fic.readlines()
Out[14]:
['\n',
 'def addtodic(txt):\n',
 '    """Messages de la forme !add id,message ; txt=\'id,message\' """\n',
 '    fic.seek(0)\n',
 "    fic.write(txt)+'\\n'\n",
 '\n',
 'def checkdic(txt):\n',
 '    """Messages de la forme !lien id ; txt=\'id\' """\n',
 "    for i in fic.readline().split('\\n'):\n",
 "        ind=i.index(',')\n",
 '        if i[:ind]==txt:\n',
 '            fic.seek(0)\n',
 '            return i[ind+1:]\n',
 '    fic.seek(0)\n',
 "    return 'Not found'\n",
 '    \n',
 'def removedic(txt):\n',
 '    """Messages de la forme !remove id ; txt=\'id\' """\n',
 '    check=True\n',
 '    while check:\n',
 '        i=fic.readline()\n',
 '        if i[:len(txt)]==txt:            \n',
 '            fic.seek(0)\n',
 '            return check\n',
 '#removedic fauxeturn check\r\n',
 "#removedic faux    tmp_file = open(filename,'w')\n",
 '            tmp_file.write(data)\n',
 '            tmp_file.close()\n',
 '        return filename\n',
 '\n',
 '    # TODO:  This should be removed when Term is refactored.\n',
 '    def write(self,data):\n',
 '        """Write a string to the default output"""\n',
 '        io.stdout.write(data)\n',
 '\n',
 '    # TODO:  This should be removed when Term is refactored.\n',
 '    def write_err(self,data):\n',
 '        """Write a string to the default error output"""\n',
 '        io.stderr.write(data)\n',
 '\n',
 '    def ask_yes_no(self, prompt, default=None):\n',
 '        if self.quiet:\n',
 '            return True\n',
 '        return ask_yes_no(prompt,default)\n',
 '\n',
 '    def show_usage(self):\n',
 '        """Show a usage message"""\n',
 '        page.page(IPython.core.usage.interactive_usage)\n',
 '\n',
 '    def extract_input_lines(self, range_str, raw=False):\n',
 '        """Return as a string a set of input history slices.\n',
 '\n',
 '        Parameters\n',
 '        ----------\n',
 '        range_str : string\n',
 '            The set of slices is given as a string, like "~5/6-~4/2 4:8 9",\n',
 '            since this function is for use by magic functions which get their\n',
 '            arguments as strings. The number before the / is the session\n',
 '            number: ~n goes n back from the current session.\n',
 '\n',
 '        Optional Parameters:\n',
 '          - raw(False): by default, the processed input is used.  If this is\n',
 '          true, the raw input history is used instead.\n',
 '\n',
 '        Note that slices can be called with two notations:\n',
 '\n',
 '        N:M -> standard python form, means including items N...(M-1).\n',
 '\n',
 '        N-M -> include items N..M (closed endpoint)."""\n',
 '        lines = self.history_manager.get_range_by_str(range_str, raw=raw)\n',
 '        return "\\n".join(x for _, _, x in lines)\n',
 '\n',
 '    def find_user_code(self, target, raw=True, py_only=False, skip_encoding_cookie=True):\n',
 '        """Get a code string from history, file, url, or a string or macro.\n',
 '\n',
 '        This is mainly used by magic functions.\n',
 '\n',
 '        Parameters\n',
 '        ----------\n',
 '\n',
 '        target : str\n',
 '\n',
 '          A string specifying code to retrieve. This will be tried respectively\n',
 '          as: ranges of input history (see %history for syntax), url,\n',
 '          correspnding .py file, filename, or an expression evaluating to a\n',
 '          string or Macro in the user namespace.\n',
 '\n',
 '        raw : bool\n',
 '          If true (default), retrieve raw history. Has no effect on the other\n',
 '          retrieval mechanisms.\n',
 '\n',
 '        py_only : bool (default False)\n',
 '          Only try to fetch python code, do not try alternative methods to decode file\n',
 '          if unicode fails.\n',
 '\n',
 '        Returns\n',
 '        -------\n',
 '        A string of code.\n',
 '\n',
 '        ValueError is raised if nothing is found, and TypeError if it evaluates\n',
 '        to an object of another type. In each case, .args[0] is a printable\n',
 '        message.\n',
 '        """\n',
 '        code = self.extract_input_lines(target, raw=raw)  # Grab history\n',
 '        if code:\n',
 '            return code\n',
 '        utarget = unquote_filename(target)\n',
 '        try:\n',
 "            if utarget.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):\n",
 '                return openpy.read_py_url(utarget, skip_encoding_cookie=skip_encoding_cookie)\n',
 '        except UnicodeDecodeError:\n',
 '            if not py_only :\n',
 '                from urllib import urlopen  # Deferred import\n',
 '                response = urlopen(target)\n',
 "                return response.read().decode('latin1')\n",
 '            raise ValueError(("\'%s\' seem to be un']
```

KABOOM ! Has anybody an explanation ? By the way, I use Python 2.7 with Enthought Canopy.

Comment: Please post your code and output here to increase the chance of people helping you.

Comment: I could not reproduce your behavior. From the command prompt, cd to **C:\Users\Julien\Desktop\PS BOT** and issue the command `type empty.txt`. What do you see?

Comment: @HaiVu How can one post a complete code here ? Any special command on the site, or do you take every single line and add 4 spaces ? That's the reason i use pastebin for pages long codes.

Comment: Also, when i type type empty.txt from the command prompt, i do not see anything. It doesn't answer, nor does it raise an error.

Comment: `fic.write(txt)+'\n'` should contain the `+'\n'` in the argument.

Comment: `for i in fic.readline().split('\n'):` doesn't make sense to me. Did you mean: `for i in fic:`? Please note thaty you should call `fic.seek(0)` just above this line. It doesn't matter whether you call it later.

Comment: To eliminate the possibility of running things in the wrong order, please add all the code to a single `.py` script, completely avoid the interactive console, and post your `.py` script and its output in your question.

Comment: Please add this to the beginning of your script (just after the `chdir`): `print ['OLD', open('empty.txt').read()]` and show us its output. This will tell us what's really in that `empty.txt` file.

Comment: I tried adding `print ['OLD', open('empty.txt').read()]` at the beginning. It didn't print anything. I didn't understand. I wrote print 1 in the console. ... It didn't print anything. I closed Canopy, and reopened it, or rather attempted to since it now crashes at starts. I'm not the sure the problem is in the script, and not my computer actually ... i'll post the results here whenever i can get them =l

Comment: To eliminate possible red herrings, don't use Canopy. Just use Python from the command-line.

Comment: `for i in fic:` is verify similar to `for i in fic.readlines().split('\n'):`. The former uses less memory (doesn't need the entire file in memory), and doesn't strip the trailing `\n` from `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a file with `'r+'`, it doesn't get truncated, it still retains its old contents. To truncate it to 0 bytes, call `fic.truncate(0)` right after opening it.

You must seek between read and write operations on the same file object (otherwise the results are undefined because of buffering), e.g. add a `fic.seek(0, 0)` (or any other seek) after the `write` call.

Comment: empty.txt was empty before being opened. I do not understand your answer. I precisely don't want to truncate it when i open it, in the code i am seeking to write.